# Check this preg_match for a card number

Tags: php, numbers, preg-match

will the below preg_match work for numbers entered like:

`1111-1111-1111-1111`
 
`1111 1111 1111 1111`

`preg_match = /^\(?([0-9]{4})\)?[- ]?([0-9]{4})[- ]?([0-9]{4})[- ]?([0-9]{4})$/`

Comment: [It may](https://regex101.com/r/uCO7wv/1).

Comment: Thanks for the link but I cannot follow it. Way too much going on.

Comment: The right panel offers an explanation of what everything does. If it is always 4 groups with optional `-` or space separator you could do `^(\d{4}(?:[- ]|$)){4}$`.

Comment: ok thanks I will check the link again then but that should be all I need. I will try this when I get home.